# ASP.MVC and IFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-2, iframe

How to make asp.mvc work in iframe ? (for example i have simple page : silverlight menu and iframe ) .I know how to change iframe src from silverlight but I dont know how to make asp.mvc work in that iframe.   Thanks for help

Comment: You need a much better description of the problem you're trying to solve. Right now it's not clear what you want inside the iFrame or what you want controlling that iFrame.

Comment: k so the question is : how can I navigate from my silverlight menu to other .aspx without refreshing whole page . Is the Iframe good solution ( i mean changing src of Iframe inside button click event handler of my silverlight app ). Are there any better solutions ? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You could point the iframe source to your ASP.NET MVC application:

```
<iframe src="http://foo.com/yourmvcapp/home/index"></iframe>
```